# Javascript won't execute in iPhone Safari

Tags: iphone, mobile-safari, javascript

I'm running into this issue only because I recently purchased an iPhone.  The javascript for a picture carousel on my website (http://www.stuartmeyerphotography.com) won't execute in Safari for iPhone.  I thought it worked on Mac Safari last I checked with a friend who had a Mac (a year ago), but now I need to go back and check that too to make sure it works on the Mac.  "View source" on my website would show the entire html page, but I've pulled the code from the body section to show here:

```
 <div align="center">
        <div id="div_container"></div>
        <p align="left">
          <script type='text/javascript'>
       carousel({id:'Photos',
          border:'',
          size_mode:'image',
          width:120,
          height:120,
          sides:8,
          steps:75,
          speed:4,
          direction:'left',
          images:['mainthumbs/babiesthumb.jpg','mainthumbs/engagementsthumb.jpg','mainthumbs/dancethumb1.jpg','mainthumbs/artistthumb.jpg','mainthumbs/portraitsthumb1.jpg','mainthumbs/seniorsthumb1.jpg','mainthumbs/wedthumb1.jpg'],
          links:['babies/babies.html','engagements/engagemainshow/engagementpictures.html','dance/dancepictures.html','artists/artists.html','portraits/portraits.html','seniors/highschoolseniors.html','weddings/weddings.html'],
          lnk_base:'',
          lnk_targets:['_iframe1',
                       '_iframe1',
                       '_iframe1',
                       '_iframe1',
                       '_iframe1',
                       '_iframe1',
                       '_iframe1' ],
          lnk_attr:['width=200,height=300,top=200,menubar=yes',
                    'width=300,height=200,left=400,scrollbars=yes',
                    'width=150,height=250,left=200,top=100',
                    ''],
          titles:['Babies',
                  'Engagements',
                  'Dance',
                  'Artists',
                  'Portraits',
                  'HS Seniors',
                  'Weddings'],
          image_border_width:1,
          image_border_color:'#E3F0A1'
          });
      </script></p>
        <p align="left">&nbsp;</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Any thoughts?   -Stuart

Comment: It's more likely the issue is within the "carousel" code than your use of it, so I doubt you'll find a solution without posting a link to that code.

Comment: Here's a link to the carousel code http://www.stuartmeyerphotography.com/websitejavascript/sshow.js. -Stuart

Answer (score 1):

I ran your js through [jslint](http://www.jslint.com/) and there were a bunch of problems.  Correcting those might clear up your issues.

Answer (score -1):

If you open safari on your mac, there should be a menu item called "Develop".  Under there is an item called user agent in which you can switch your desktop browser to behave like the iPhone mobile safari browser.  It'll be easier to troubleshoot and conduct your iPhone compatibility tests there.

Depending on what you have installed, some options include:

Mobile Safari 4.0.2 - iPhone
Mobile Safari 4.0.2 - iPod Touch
Mobile Safari 3.2.2 - iPad
etc...